# How can I set mutt as the default mail client when I click on a 'mailto' in a webpage?

Tags: linux, email, mutt

I wanted to start `mutt` in terminal when I click on some `mailto:` tag in a webpage.  Is that possible? Currently Firefox starts, which I really don't favor; it's slow loading and unnecessary.

Answer (score 10):

First you need to ensure that there's a `.desktop` file which is required by
the XDG specification. For GUI programs the chance is good that there already
is a suitable `.desktop` file, for terminal applications usually you have to
create your own one. Check out the directory `/usr/share/applications` for
existing files. Maybe there is already a `mutt.desktop` file. If there isn't,
create one.

Then edit the file `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and add the
following line

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/mailto=mutt.desktop;
```

This registers mutt with the `mailto` handler. You can confirm a successful registration with

```
xdg-mime query default 'x-scheme-handler/mailto'
```

which should output `mutt.desktop`. Now you can click on “mailto” in chromium
and a terminal should pop up with a mutt instance. No need to even
restart the desktop session or the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a script that's specifies the terminal that you want `mutt` to open in. Then, in Firefox, you can associate this script with mailto links. For example, if you are using terminator, you can create the following script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
terminator -x "mutt '$@'"
```

In my case, I have a persistent drop-down terminator, so I want it in a new tab. I also need a 256 colour palette, so I use

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
terminator --new-tab -x "TERM=xterm-256color; mutt '$@'"
```

FWIW this is my full script, which also unhides terminator (if hidden), using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, and brings it to the front.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

terminator --new-tab -x "TERM=xterm-256color; mutt '$@'"

# If necessary, unhide and focus terminator window.
windowlist=$(xprop -root | sed -rn 's/_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING\(WINDOW\): window id # (.*)/\1/p' | tr -d ',')
terminator_visible=false
for i in $windowlist; do
  [[ $(xprop -id $i | grep WM_CLASS\(STRING\)) == 'WM_CLASS(STRING) = "terminator", "Terminator"' ]] && terminator_visible=true && term_id=$i
done

if [[ $terminator_visible == false ]]; then # it's hidden
  xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+space
elif [[ $(xprop -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) | grep WM_CLASS\(STRING\)) != 'WM_CLASS(STRING) = "terminator", "Terminator"' ]]; then # it's visible, but not active
  xdotool windowactivate $term_id 2> /dev/null # Gives error; not sure why. XGetWindowProperty[_NET_WM_DESKTOP] failed (code=1)
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Which desktop environment are you running? You need to check it's MIME type handler's settings on how to set a specific handler for these kind of things.

Comment: OpenBox , i just don't know how to get the mimetype , it's not a file , i can't just run 'mimetype /path/to/file' to identify it

Answer (score 0):

You can use xdg-mime to register a default application. In that case you run on a terminal:

```
xdg-mime default mutt.desktop 'x-scheme-handler/mailto'
```

And you can check if it worked by running:

```
xdg-mime query default 'x-scheme-handler/mailto'
```